# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'flush'

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to solve Boston house price prediction problem,but it has this error

`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'flush'`
and this:
`

```
Cell In [53], line 7, in load_data()
      5 def load_data():
      6     datafile= pd.read_csv("housing.csv",sep=',')
----> 7     data = np.fromfile(datafile)
      8     feature_names = ['RM', 'LSTAT', 'PTRATIO', 'MEDV']
      9     feature_num = len(feature_names)
```

`

here's a part of my code
`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

def load_data():
    datafile= pd.read_csv("housing.csv",sep=',')
    data = np.fromfile(datafile)
    feature_names = ['RM', 'LSTAT', 'PTRATIO', 'MEDV']
    feature_num = len(feature_names)

    data = data.reshape(data.shape[0] // feature_num, feature_num)

    ratio = 0.8
    offset = int(data.shape[0] * ratio)
    training = data[:offset]

    maximums, minimums, avge = training.max(axis=0), training.min(axis=0), training.sum(axis=0) / training.shape[0]
```

`

the word "flush" doesn't appear in my code or in my data
can anyone give me some idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading the housing.csv file with `pd.read_csv`, which converts it to a [`Dataframe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) object. This leads to the error, because [`np.fromfile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html) expects a file (str or path), not a Dataframe.

To get rid of the error, replace the first to statements in the load_data function with a single suitable numpy function such as [`np.genfromtext`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html).

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

def load_data():
    data = np.genfromtxt('housing.csv', delimiter=',')
    feature_names = ['RM', 'LSTAT', 'PTRATIO', 'MEDV']
    # [...]
```